# Is Ballerina ready for production?

Tags: wso2, ballerina, ballerina-composer

I find Ballerina a great solution to create an api gateway layer.
Is it ready for production?
Is someone using it in production?

Thanks

Gianni

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We released the 0.8.0 version of Ballerina just 2-3 weeks ago. No one is using Ballerina in production at the moment. Version 1.0.0 of Ballerina will be ready by this summer.

We would encourage you to implement your scenarios in Ballerina and give us feedback for improvement.

Sameera.

Comment: Hi Sameera, is it ready now? ;)